# Problems de Serial data type in DBeaver & PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I´m a new user (noob) of [**Dbeaver**](https://dbeaver.jkiss.org/) (community edition) and [**PostgreSQL**](https://www.postgresql.org/), and I was having  big trouble in defining **an auto-incremented Primary Key** in any table, so I would like to know how to be able to define an auto-incremented primary key using **DBeaver**, answers must no include these trials:

1. Defining the primary key as serial (***DBeaver*** will change it automatically to int2-4-8 even when defining the **Primary Key** as not null).
2. Defining a new sequence in **DBeaver** (*the best way to define a new sequence is throw **pgAdmin4** and you may not be that successful to assign it to the table's **Primary Key** if your a noob just like I´m either in **DBeaver** or in **pgAdmin4***).

Comment: serial is int2-4-8, plus sequence. why not using SQL statements?..

Comment: There is no real data type `serial`. It's a short hand for an integer column with a sequence as the default value. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL So the best way to create a table with a serial data type is to define it as a serial. Apparently DBeaver displays the table the same way as `psql`: https://imgur.com/a/m8TI4

Comment: @VaoTsun, int2-4-8, I meant (int2 - int4 - int8), and what should be that SQL statement ??

Comment: My problem with **DBeaver** is that I can't generate a sequence from with in the program, nor define a serial type as I can do in **pgAdmin4**,  and even when I manage to bypass all these problems, when ever I try to add a new record from within **DBeaver**, it doesn't generate an automatic primary key number, it gives me an error message that the primary key have a null value, when it it was defined as Not Null

Comment: please update your post with existing table DDL and clearly define what you try to do and what is not working

Answer (score 2):

I also could not find this in the DBeaver GUI. You could issue the following sql query against your table:

```
ALTER TABLE public."Customer"
    ALTER COLUMN customer_id ADD GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY ( INCREMENT 1 START 1 MINVALUE 1 );
```