# How to make a simple auto increment field with postgresql in dbeaver 21.0?

Tags: postgresql, auto-increment, dbeaver

"SERIAL" type does not exist yet, so how can we do the basic auto increment field in DBeaver 21.O via his GUI ?

Comment: `serial` is somewhat discouraged to begin with, you should use an `identity` column anyways: `create table foo (id integer generated always as identity)` - but `create table foo (id serial)` should work just fine regardless of the SQL client

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create auto incrementing / SERIAL id column's on DBeaver using PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52177610/how-to-create-auto-incrementing-serial-id-columns-on-dbeaver-using-postgresql)

Comment: @nbk : no because the solution gived is about the famous serial type which does not exist anymore.... But thanks.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I speak with DBeaver GUI but thanks also.

Comment: You should be creating your tables through SQL scripts that are stored in Git, properly managed with a schema migration tool. Don't use a GUI for that.

Comment: serial is int(4) in dbbeaver and since 2017 they didn't find a good solution, make what @a_horse_with_no_name said, or use another tool

Answer (score 1):

You can set "serial" as data type with DBeaver GUI

[serialViaDBeaver](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5csFq.png)

And why serial type does not exist yet? I can see it in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html)

Comment: No I can't otherwise I dont lose my time to post my problem on this forum ;)